# How can I take multiple values from object without calling object's name everytime?

Tags: kotlin

I have class `Weekdays` which has 7 parameters. I have also `entity` object which contains all required arguments to satisfy `Weekdays` class.
Normally I would write something like this to init this class:

```
   Weekdays(entity.isMonday,
            entity.isTuesday,
            entity.isWednesday,
            entity.isThursday,
            entity.isFriday,
            entity.isSaturday,
            entity.isSunday)
```

But everytime I need to call `entity` object to get value from this. Is there any keyword that would allow me not to call `entity` every time I want to get value from it?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements, you could add a secondary constructor to your `Weekdays` class, which calls the primary constructor in the way shown.

Or you could add a factory method to its companion object, which can use `with` to simplify a little, e.g.:

```
class Weekdays(/*...*/) {
    /*
    ...
    */
    companion object {
        fun Weekdays(entity: Entity) = with(entity) {
            Weekdays(isMonday, isTuesday, isWednesday, isThursday, isFriday, isSaturday, isSunday)
        }
    }
}
```

Or you could restructure `Weekdays` so that it has an array or other structure, instead of named fields.